# UIPageControl UIControlEventValueChanged - how do I know previous value?

Tags: ios, uikit, uipagecontrol

I've got a `UIPageControl` object working great in my app, except that I am not handling the default 'tap to advance/decrement' behavior.

I need to:

- handle it in my app
- know what the current and previous values of the `UIPageControl` is.

I know I can capture the 'new' value on `UIControlEventValueChanged`, but how would I know the 'old'?  I manually `setCurrentPage` in several places in my code, but saving the old state somewhere there could lead to bugs and is sort of a hack I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a property to keep the previous page, but why not define one? You can keep all the previous page numbers in an `NSMutableArray` object and;

- When you are about to go to a new page, add the current one to the array before you go,
- Whenever you want to come back a previous page, get the `lastObject` of you array and remove it.

  ```
  - (NSInteger)previousPageNumber
  {
      NSInteger pageNumber = 0;
      if(self.previousPagesArray.count > 0)
      {
          pageNumber = [[self.previousPagesArray lastObject] intValue];
          [self.previousPagesArray removeLastObject];
      }

      return pageNumber;
  }
  ```

and

```
-(void)goToNextPage
{
    NSNumber *pageNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.pageControl.currentPage];
    [self.previousPagesArray addObject:pageNumber];
    //go to next page
}
```